# Fill form then slide left to reveal another with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have 3 forms. I'd like to show each separately. Having the user fillout and then have the completed form slide to the left, and then revealing the proceeding form.

```
$('.button-action').click(function() {
    $('.firstForm').animate({left: '-=150px'}, 500);
});
```

How would I go about making this happen?

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQaSr/13/)** that I've tried to work with.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you expect the user to progress?  By clicking 'apply'?

Comment: @Michael_B yes. Sorry I forgot that.

Comment: @Michael_B I made an edit to the fiddle. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the divs to have a class called 'wizard' (because that's the way I see what you are trying to do)  you can change that however you'd like.

HTML

```
<div class="promo">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="signup" class="wizard">
            <div class="heading">
                 <h1>Just need your email to get started</h1>

            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input class="signup-email" type="text" placeholder="Email address" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button data-next-id="form1" validationDiv="signup" class="continue button button-action">Apply</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="form1" class="wizard">
             <h1>One more to go</h1>

            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Country" />
            <button data-next-id="form2" validationDiv="form1" class="continue button button-action">One more</button>
        </div>
        <div id="form2" class="wizard">
             <h1>Last one</h1>

            <input type="text" class="input-text" placeholder="Company Name" />
            <button validationDiv="form2" class="button button-action">Done</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".wizard").hide();
$("#signup").show();
$(".continue").click(function () {
    var valid = true;
    $("#" + $(this).attr("validationDiv")).find("input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") valid = false;
    });
    if (valid) {
        $(".wizard").slideUp();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("data-next-id")).slideDown();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQaSr/14/)